# ng-disabled validation prblem

Tags: angularjs, validation, autocomplete

I have problem with validation, im using ng-disabled on button while form is not validated. I have 2 inputs in form, the problem is that button gets enabled when i enter value in second input while first is empty (first uses autocomplete), but otherwise it works, i dont want that user when enter just 'neto' to button gets enabled, it looks like angular dont sees that angucomplete as part of the form.

```
    <form name="usForm" role="form" novalidate>

  <div>
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Stavka</th>
        <th>Količina</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>        
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div angucomplete-alt
            id="norma.idartcle"
            placeholder="Aricle"
            pause="100"
            selected-object="object"
            local-data="getarticles"
            search-fields="pass,name"
            title-field="pass,name"
            description-field="norm"
            minlength="2"
            input-class="form-control form-control-small"
            match-class="highlight"
            input-changed="norm.idarticle"
            field-required="true"
            text-no-results="It doesnt exist"
            text-searching="Searching..."
            >
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
           <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="neto" id="neto" placeholder="Neto" ng-model="norm.neto"  ng-maxlength="6" required />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary"  ng-disabled="usForm.$invalid" ng-click="addNorm(object)">Add</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default"  ng-click="clearForm()">Leave</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to follow the examples gives at ...

http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/

in particular notice the validation example - Example 8

Here ALL fields are angucomplete - There is no example where angucomplete is mixed with normal inputs. That does not mean angucomplete does not work when mixed with normal inputs it just means it might not!

Also the examples on angucomplete are using angular 1.4.6 so make sure it is not an angular version issue.

Comment: version is not the problem, i still cant make it work

Comment: i suggest you simplify your solution as much as possible and build it up slowly - start from a working basic example, copy and paste from Example 8 above and build it slowly making sure you are not breaking anything